# Can I manipulate the way that variables change in Java?

Tags: java

If the die shows a 6, the player doesn't move at all on this turn and also forfeits the next turn.

To accomplish this, I have tried an integer type warning marker variable for the player and an integer type time counter variable.

If the die shows 6, I want to increment the warning marker variable by 1 during the first run(and have the while loop do nothing), then keep the value at 1 during the second run (while loop will not work), then lower it back down to 0 for the third run of the while loop (so the while loop will work). The marker will stay at zero unless the die shows a 6 again, after which the same process will repeat.

I have a while loop like this:

```
while the warning marker is equal to 0 {
    Do Stuff
    if the die shows a 6, the warning marker increases by 1.
    the time counter also increases by 1.
}
```

How do I manipulate the variables to get the result that I need? Or is my partially complete method absolutely off in terms of logic?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can u tell me if this works for you?

```
   flag=true;    
    while condition{
      if flag==true{
         if die == 6
         {
           flag=false;
           continue;}
         } 
         else { Do STUFF }
     } else 
         {
            flag==true;
          }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you want to reword this problem.

This is what I understood. You have a warning marker.
You have a loop that checks whether the marker is 0, if it is then you do something.
If the die is a six, you will increase the warning marker. If its new value is 3, then you will reset it to 0. Meanwhile, the time counter is always increasing.

If this is correct, I think you want something like:

```
int warningMarker = 0;
int timeMarker = 0;

while (true) {
    if (die == 6) {
        ++warningMarker;
        if (warningMarker == 3) {
            warningMarker = 0;
        }
    }

    if (warningMarker == 0) {
        doSomething();
    }

    ++timeMarker;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Java is Object-Oriented Pragramming language. Use this feature.

See following pseudocode and let me know if you have problem in undestanding it.

Create a class `Player` as following:

```
class Player
{
    boolean skipChance = false;

    ... // Other fields
    ... //
}
```

Change your `while` as following:

```
while(isGameOn())
{
    Player p = getCurrentPlayer();
    if( ! p.skipChance)
    {
        int val = p.throwDice();
        if(val == 6)
        {
            p.skipChance = true;
            continue; // control moves to while.
        }
        // Do stuff
    }
    else
    {
        p.skipChance = false;
    }
}
```